# Recording a live streaming video

Tags: windows-xp, video, streaming, recording

A live video screens on [Waheguru Live](http://wahegurulive.com/live/) every Saturday and I want to record the live broadcast.

I need freeware only. I'm on Windows XP SP3 (32 Bit)

Answer (score 1):

[CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) should be able to record it easily. It records as AVI and gives you the option to convert it to SWF.

You may want to disable hardware acceleration while recording for a smoother video as well.

Comment: ok i found this http://www.digitaldrake.com/how-to-use-camstudio-streaming-video-recorder/

Comment: Nice find, it seems like a good overview!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you [Quick Screen Recorder](http://www.etrusoft.com/qsr.exe).It's free and useful...

Comment: will it record sound also?

Comment: yes it supports audio recording too...